# Can we use user defined hierarchy in DAX ?

Tags: tabular

Can we use user defined hierarchy in DAX and then EVALUATE to see the whole hierarchy items as result ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no hierarchy functions in DAX.  The best you can do is to just return a list of your  hierarchy columns.  So suppose you had a columns called Level1, Level2, and Level3 in a table called DaxTab.  The best you could do to dump the contents of the hierarchy would be:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARZE(
    DaxTab,
    [DaxTab]Level1,
    [DaxTab]Level2, 
    [DaxTab]Level3
)
ORDER BY
    [DaxTab]Level1,
    [DaxTab]Level2, 
    [DaxTab]Level3
```